# PHP MySQL UNION SELECT not working the way expected

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, union

here's the thing, if I do just the first select it works perfect, but when I do the UNION it echoes Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\bla, bla, bla.

I did a searched for similar question and/or problem but none of the found seemed to give me a clue of how to fix this.

```
<?php
$moncols='col1,col2,col3,col4';
$main = "SELECT $moncols FROM table1 WHERE col4 = 'yes'
         UNION
         SELECT $moncols FROM table2 WHERE col4 = 'yes'
         UNION
         SELECT $moncols FROM table3 WHERE col4 = 'yes'
         UNION
         SELECT $moncols FROM table4 WHERE col4 = 'yes'
         UNION
         SELECT $moncols FROM table5 WHERE col4 = 'yes'";
$resoult = $mon -> query($main);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resoult)){
$myStuff=$row['col4'];
$otherStuff=$row['col3'];
echo $myStuff. ' - ' .$otherStuff. '<br>';
}
?>
```

Than's :)

Comment: Have you tried your query using for example phpMyAdmin? BTW do you really want to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? (and why `resoult` is not `result`? :)

Comment: I rune the code provided by  @zombat and the error appeared, I was misspelling a column, than I rune the query in PHP MyADMIN and yes, that was the problem. It was a misspelled column, everything else was ok... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an error in your query.  Perhaps one of your tables is missing one of those columns.  Whatever the case, `$resoult` is not a valid mysqli result.  Try adding some error checking to find the problem:

```
$resoult = $mon->query($main);
if (! resoult) {
    echo "MySQL error: " . $mon->error);
}
```

Comment: I rune the query in PHP MyADMIN and yes, that was the problem. It was a misspelled column, everything else was ok... Thanks a lot.